# how to get the propert of object that collect data from two tables and update column?

Tags: php, laravel

I want to update the **ResidentID** in the Room table. Where ResidentID is a foreign key refrence from **Group Table**. it is working well when I update ResidentId =2 manually, but I want to send the Group id to the ResidentID  from the $allot_apps object.

```
public function View_GroupStudent()
{  
    $caps = Rooms::selectRaw('count(id) as c')->count();
    $allot_apps = AllotmentApps::join('Groups','Groups.id','AllotmentApps.grpID')- 
    >orderBy('Groups.Group_CGPA', 'Desc')->get()->groupBy(
      function($item) { 
        return $item->grpID;
    }
  )->take($caps);
  $merits=Rooms::all()->toArray();
  foreach ($merits as $key) {
 $merits=Rooms::where('id',$key)->Update(['ResidentID'=>'2']);
  }
    return view('admin.ViewGroups', compact('allot_apps'));
}
```

[$allot_apps](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UHhn5.jpg)

[$allt-apps variables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FVQZr.jpg)

[$merit](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Jcxr.jpg)

**AllotmentApps Model**

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class AllotmentApps extends Model
{
//

protected $fillable = [
    'sname', 'fname', 'Roll_No','cnic','domicile','cgpa','Department','Session','degreeProgram','contactNo','GcontactNo','preAddress','permAddress','fee','challanNo','app_status','fee_status','grpID',
];


protected $primaryKey = 'id';
protected $table = 'AllotmentApps';

 public function groups()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Groups');
}
  }
```

**Groups Model**

```
 <?php

  namespace App;

 use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

  class Groups extends Model
{
//
protected $fillable = ['Group_CGPA',];

protected $primaryKey = 'id';

public function allotmentApps()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\AllotmentApps');
}
   }
```

**Room Model**

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Rooms extends Model


protected $fillable = ['id','HostelID','ResidentID'];

protected $primaryKey = 'id';
 {
   public function hostels()
{
   
   return $this->belongsTo('App\Hostels');
}
  }
```

Comment: show us the `var_dump($mertis) & var_dump($allot_apps)`

Comment: I've edited the question and added the dump pictures

Comment: please have a look, on these pictures

Comment: Could you show us the models of the tables? As a side node, you're overwriting your merits variable in your foreach loop.

Comment: I've added the model into this question, please have a look on this and let me know where is my fault. How can I acieve my end goal ?